# cx_Freeze library.zip FileNotFound error

Tags: python, cx-freeze

This is my setup.py file:

```
import sys

from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

sys.path.append(r'../lib/driver/src/')
sys.path.append(r'../lib/instrument/src/')
sys.path.append(r'../lib/routing/src/')

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os", "pyvisa", "pyodbc", "numpy", "scipy", "skrf",],
                     "includes" : ["matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg", 'tkinter.filedialog'],
                     "include_files": [('C:\\temp\\py34x64\\Lib\\site-packages\\scipy-0.15.0-py3.4-win-amd64.egg\\scipy\\special\\_ufuncs.pyd','_ufuncs.pyd')],
                     "zip_includes": [('C:\\Users\\user\\workspace\\routing-app\\lib\\scikit-rf\\skrf\\data\\ntwk1.s2p', 'ntwk1.s2p')]}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    #base = "Win32GUI"
    base = 'Console'

setup(  name = "SomeName",
        version = "1.0",
        description = "Some Description",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("main.py", base=base)])
```

Hence, i explicit tell cx_freeze to include ntwk1.s2p into the library.zip file, which it does.

However, when i run the exe file:

```
File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scikit_rf-0.15.dev0-py3.4.egg\skrf\data\__init__.py", line 26, in <module> ntwk1 = Network(os.path.join(pwd, 'ntwk1.s2p'))
  File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scikit_rf-0.15.dev0-py3.4.egg\skrf\network.py", line 363, in __init__
    fid = get_fid(file,'rb')
  File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\scikit_rf-0.15.dev0-py3.4.egg\skrf\util.py", line 164, in get_fid
    return open(file, *args, **kwargs)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\\Users\\user\\workspace\\routing-app\\src\\build\\exe.win-amd64-3.4\\library.zip\\skrf\\data\\ntwk1.s2p'
```

So why is the application not able to found the file inside library.zip? It feels like the cx_freeze has not unzipped the library.zip when the util.py module is executed. Any ideas?

Comment: cx_Freeze does not unzip library.zip - Python loads the modules in there directly from the zip file. That often doesn't work for packages that have data files like that, though. My tool [Pynsist](http://pynsist.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) might work better for that.